# Upgrading to Ruby on Rails 3.1: the 'jquery_ujs.js' file should be deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, upgrade

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I am upgrading my RoR to the version 3.1.0. I am following the [Upgrading to Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) railscast and on the time *05:14* he deletes all related jQuery files present in the `assets/javascripts/` directory.

In the linked railscast there are these 3 files:

```
jquery.js
jquery.min.js
rails.js
```

On my machine there are these 3 files:

```
jquery.js
jquery.min.js
jquery_ujs.js
```

The difference is that I have the `jquery_ujs.js` file instead of the `rails.js` file... **what I have to do? That is, should I delete the `jquery_ujs.js` file?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is "yes".  Delete those files as they are no longer needed and will just conflict with the new built in ujs files.

If you, like me, used to use the jQuery-rails gem you should first delete the rails.js and jquery_ujs.js files.  Then remove the

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
```

line from your development.rb file (I had to).

Change your application.js to look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Then change your application.css to look like this:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear since I ran into this issue as well.  The FILE is deleted, but the lines
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
in application.js are needed.